# Tensorflow Lite Object Detection - Value of the Detection Object

Tags: tensorflow

I had implemented the pre-trained model for Tensorflow Lite but the values of the detection object are not based on the target (e.g when it detect only one target T1 mush have value and T2 - T4 is 0)

Research that based on my research:

1. When Tensorflow detect the same object, it will still take it as a new detecting object.
2. There is no way to track the object whether is it a new or same detecting object unless using a deep learning model for appearance feature extraction
3. In order to use a deep learning model, we need to make sure that we trained the model based on how we want to make it to be sticky.
4. We need to also perform inference on each frame of the camera stream with the model.

Questions I have is based on my research:

1. How do we train the model?
2. How long does it take to train tensorflow?
3. What’s the result we can expect if we train it?

If there is any alternatives or other ways, please do share with me.

I try to do it programmitcally by using a function to track the object that has been detected based on the bounding box, label and confidence (score) of the detected object. I was expecting it should work as I was thinking it should can be solved without needing to use a model.